# MKMapView is nil, but the IBOutlet is correct initialized

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am making my first XCode project and I want to make an app where you can click on a `tableviewcell` and then you can see are directed to the next `detailpage` where the location is on the map. The problem is that I get a thread when i run the app:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and in my output i see that (`MKMapView!`) nil is.

This is my code on my `MapViewController` (the detailpage where the map is supposed to be)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate{

  @IBOutlet weak var mijnMap: MKMapView!

  var currentDetail: Parking? {
    didSet {
      showInfoDetail()
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  func showInfoDetail() {
    if let detail = currentDetail {
        let coordinaat = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(detail.latitude)
            , longitude: CLLocationDegrees(detail.longitude))
        MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinaat)
        mijnMap.centerCoordinate = coordinaat
        mijnMap.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinaat, 1000, 1000)
        let parkingAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        parkingAnnotation.coordinate = coordinaat
        parkingAnnotation.title = detail.title
        parkingAnnotation.subtitle = detail.city

        mijnMap.addAnnotation(parkingAnnotation)
    }
  }
}
```

I get the threat on this line `mijnMap.centerCoordinate = coordinaat`
Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: do you set parking from anothe VC ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that because of `didSet` in

```
var currentDetail: Parking? {
  didSet {
   showInfoDetail()
 }
}
```

when you try to set `currentDetail` from another VC  the call to method `showInfoDetail` triggers and this happen before the VC is presented which means prior to view loading resulting in a crash as all IBOutlets are not yet been initialized , so delay the call to it in `viewDidAppear` or check the map before usage

```
var currentDetail: Parking? {
  didSet { 
    if mijnMap != nil {
       showInfoDetail()
    }
  }
}
```

Note in second option you have at call `showInfoDetail` in `viewDidLoad` / `viewDidAppear`  , I'm not suggesting removing `didSet` as you may want to change that string value in `MapViewController` and trigger the same function every change